# Angular: Error received at the time of capturing field

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I have the following form:

```
<form class="form-margin cart-container" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <div style="flex-direction: column">
        <app-cart-item class="cart-item" *ngFor="let pr of productRecordList" [productRecord]="pr"></app-cart-item>
        <br />
        <p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight: bolder">Total ${{ getTotal() }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cart-item-details">
        <!-- <input type="text" cols="35" rows="2" placeholder="(minimum 3 characters)" required minlength="3" [(ngModel)]="fullName" #ffullName="ngModel"/> -->

        <p>Full Name</p>
        <input type="text" cols="35" rows="2" placeholder="(minimum 3 characters)" required minlength="3" />
        <br />
        <p>Address</p>
        <input type="text" cols="35" rows="2" placeholder="(minimum 6 characters)" required minlength="6" />
        <br />
        <p>Credit card number</p>
        <input type="text" cols="35" rows="2" placeholder="(16-digits number)" required minlength="16" maxlength="16" />
        <br />

        <p>We will never share your payment details to anyone</p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" routerLink="/confirmation" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The TypeScript class is provided:

```
import { ProductsService } from './../../services/products.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import ProductRecord from 'src/app/services/products.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-cart',
    templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
    productRecordList: ProductRecord[] = [];

    fullName: string = '';
    address: string = '';
    cardNumber: number = 0;

    totalPrice: number = 0.0;

    constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.productRecordList = this.productsService.getProductsFromCart();
    }

    getTotal(): number {
        this.totalPrice = this.productsService.getProductsPriceTotal();

        return this.totalPrice;
    }

    submitForm(): void {

      // console.log(this.fullName);
      // console.log(this.totalPrice);
    }
}
```

I would like to capture the `fullName` value upon the form submission, so I changed the `<input>` tag as below:

```
<input type="text" cols="35" rows="2" placeholder="(minimum 3 characters)" required minlength="3" [(ngModel)]="fullName"/>
```

This is so that I can capture the value in the `fullName` field in the respective class. However, that breaks the code.

I receive an error:

```
ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
```

How do I capture the field upon submission?

Comment: Did you import FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule inside your page's module?

Comment: Yes, other forms are working. I guess the issue is I try to use `[(ngModel)]="fullName"` inside the `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

<input type="text" cols="35" rows="2" placeholder="(minimum 3 characters)" required minlength="3" [(ngModel)]="fullName" name="fullName"/>

Comment: This is how I fixed it after reading another answer. Very helpful though.

Comment: Thak you! I pleased if it helped!

Answer (score 1):

When you use @angular/forms Angular turn your form in a FormGroup.
When you add [ngModel] on your input, Angular will create a FormControl inside your FormGroup with the given name attribute.
When you decide to use [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" this doesn't occur.

So you can fix your problem adding `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` to your input.

Sorry for my poor English, I hope I made it clear.

Comment: Do I need to put this `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` in the `<input>` tag?

Comment: <input type="text" cols="35" rows="2" placeholder="(minimum 3 characters)" required minlength="3" [(ngModel)]="fullName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">

Comment: Thanks, though I solve it as provided by another answer.